# Auto Accept Android Bluetooth Pairing

Tags: android, bluetooth

All
   I need to programmatically accept pairing request from a remote device. Remote device is an embedded device which change the pairing passkey with every .5 hour. When ever my android device become discoverable remote device try to pair with my phone and prompt for the passkey. My application  know the passkey to be set since the same algorithm is running on my phone, but the user doesn't aware about it. I need to set this passkey for the remote device and accept the request programmatically with out any user interaction.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Shibu

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537313/auto-accept-bluetooth-pairing-possible/30362554#30362554

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't think it could be possible to automatically accept a pairing in android, it's not safe

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537313/auto-accept-bluetooth-pairing-possible/30362554#30362554