# Bluetooth Insecure Connection asks for pairing

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, zebra-printers

After bluetooth 2.1 can I still create an insecure channel between Android and connect to other device, **WITHOUT** asking the user, to confirm the pairing? I've tried:

```
BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getRemoteDevice(TSC_MAC_ADDRESS);
bluetoothDevice.createBond();
BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket = bluetoothDevice.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(WELL_KNOWN_UUID);
bluetoothSocket.connect();
```

But the device keeps presenting me a dialog where I have to confirm.
I'm upgrading to a new printer (different brand) and the old one (Zebra), never asked me for confirmation, so I'm pretty sure that was possible, even if I've read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28029973/2373113) that states the opposite. Thanks in advance.