# Android : Programmatically pair a bluetooth device; Incorrect pin or passkey on some devices?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, pairing

**What I want to do :**

I'm developping an Android specific app where I must pair a device automatically, without even displaying the usual dialog box to ask the user to input a passcode.

My code is mainly inspired from these two stackOverflow Threads :

[Auto-accept bluetooth pairing possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537313/auto-accept-bluetooth-pairing-possible)

[Programmatically pairing with a BLE device on Android 4.4+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38055699/programmatically-pairing-with-a-ble-device-on-android-4-4)

**The problem I'm facing :**

- device #1 on android 5.1.1  : Ok
- device #2 on android 6.0    : Ok
- device #3 on android 5.1    : couldn't pair because of an incorrect pin or passkey
- device #4 on android 5.1    : couldn't pair because of an incorrect pin or passkey

I can't tell if android version has something to do with this issue. Do you have any idea that may help me make it work on devices #3 and #4 ?

Comment: could you provide device list also?

Comment: What kind of devices do you want to pair with? Is it some custom hardware or is it other smartphones?

Comment: Which role does device play? Is it central, and phone is peripheral?

Comment: Thank you all for your answers.
By "device", I mean a "no-brand Android tablet". I do not work with these anymore, and I'm not facing this problem. I do not have a solution for this, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same issue, that my BT code was working fine on other versions but failing on `5.1 & 5.1.1`.

But then I tried [Android-BluetoothSPPLibrary](https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-BluetoothSPPLibrary), which worked on android `5.1 & 5.1.1`.

So, try this and review his code, which might give you a clue about what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
We have new devices and I'm not facing this problem anymore.