# API 15 (4.04) Bluetooth auto pair with pin

Tags: android, bluetooth, pairing

I want to pair to a Bluetooth device automatically. The app that I'm developing must be for API 15 (4.04). I tried different solutions with reflection but nothing seems to work.
The pin is 0000. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Please provide any code you've tried so far.

Comment: I tried different solutions from stackoverflow like : https://stackoverflow.com/a/30362554/7166724

Comment: And like this https://stackoverflow.com/q/17168263/7166724 Thanks!